# Heat Equation with In-Depth Radiation Exact Solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, temperature, differential-equations

> I am looking to solve the heat conduction equation in a semi-infinite solid with in-depth radiation on the domain $-\infty < x < 0$. The governing equation of this problem is:
>
> $$\rho c \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + q_r \kappa \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x}$$
>   where
>   $$T(x,0) = T_0\\
> T(-\infty,t) = T_0\\
> \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0$$

Making the substitution of $\theta = T - T_0$, $\alpha = k/(\rho c)$, and $\beta = q_r \kappa /(\rho c)$, the problem is simplified to:

$$\theta_t = \alpha \theta_{xx} + \beta \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x}$$ 
where 
$$\theta(x,0) = 0\\
\theta(-\infty,t) = 0\\
\theta_x(0,t) = 0$$

Applying the Laplace Transform in time ($\mathscr{L}\{\theta(x,t)\} = \Theta(x,s)$) to the equation yields:

$$
s \Theta = \alpha \Theta_{xx} + \frac{\beta \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x}}{s}
$$
where
$$\Theta(-\infty,s) = 0\\
\Theta_x(0,s) = 0$$

Splitting the solution into a homogeneous and particular solution and substituting $\tau = \sqrt{s/\alpha}$ yields:

$$
\Theta_H = c_1 \mathrm{e}^{\tau x} + c_2 \mathrm{e}^{-\tau x}\\
\Theta_P = c_3 \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x}\\
$$

Plugging the particular solution back into the ODE for $\Theta$ yields:
$$
c_3 = \frac{\beta}{s (\alpha \kappa^2 - s)}
$$

Solving the constant temperature boundary condition at $x=-\infty$ yields:
$$
c_2 = 0
$$

Solving the zero gradient boundary condition at $x=0$ yields:
$$
c_1 = \frac{\beta}{\tau s (s - \alpha \kappa^2)}
$$

Combining all of the above into a single equation:
$$
\Theta(x,s) = \Theta_H + \Theta_P\\
\Theta_H = \frac{\beta}{\tau s (s - \alpha \kappa^2)}\mathrm{e}^{\tau x} \\
\Theta_P = \frac{\beta}{s (\alpha \kappa^2 - s)} \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x}
$$

At this point the solution is found by simply taking the inverse Laplace Transform of $\Theta_H$ and $\Theta_P$ separately.

$$
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{\Theta_P\} = \beta \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x} \mathscr{L}^{-1}\{(s(\alpha \kappa^2 - s))^{-1}\} =  \frac{(\mathrm{e}^{\alpha \kappa^2 t} - 1)}{\alpha \kappa}\beta \mathrm{e}^{\kappa x}
$$

Now, what is the Inverse Laplace Transform of $\Theta_H$?

Comment: DOH! I'll fix that and update the post in the morning. Not at my computer at the moment and editing LaTeX/Stack Exchange on my phone is painful.

Comment: The derivation should be correct now through to determining $\Theta_H$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple I am obtaining the following result for the inverse Laplace transform that you need:

[image]

Please do right click on the image to enlarge it.

Then, the complete solution is:

[image]

Please do right click on the image to enlarge it.